# Como identificar que o usuário está na pagina do meu site com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um script para identificar se o usuário está no site ou não, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Minha duvida é a seguinte, quero saber se o usuário está na minha página, por exemplo se o usuário for pra outra aba conta como se ele tivesse saído, se ele voltar pra aba do meu site, ele estará novamente no site.

Estou usando PHP.

Comment: Será necessário um linguagem server-side, como PHP, Python, Ruby (com framework Rails), etc.

Comment: Estou utilizando PHP, teria algum exemplo?

Comment: você quer contar os visitantes? Ou você precisa de dados relevantes deste visitante (tipo por alguma autenticação como login e senha)

Comment: Minha duvida é a seguinte, quero saber se o usuário está na minha página, por exemplo se o usuário for pra outra aba conta como se ele tivesse saído, se ele voltar pra aba do meu site, ele estará novamente no site.

Comment: Sim é possivel, mas não é algo que seja "preciso", ou seja não é possivel ser em tempo real.

Comment: Pode me ajudar com um exemplo simples  @Guilherme Nascimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/1518921) você pode usar o [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) que permite detectar se uma página está ocultado.

Navegadores que suportam:

- Chrome 13+
- Internet Explorer 10+
- Firefox 10+
- Opera 12.10+ <sup>[[Notas](https://dev.opera.com/blog/page-visibility-api-support-in-opera-12-10/)]</sup>

O código a seguir faz uso da API e também tenta prover a funcionalidade semelhante para alguns navegadores sem compatibilidade.

```
(function() {
  var hidden = "hidden";

  // Standards:
  if (hidden in document)
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
  // IE 9 and lower:
  else if ("onfocusin" in document)
    document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
  // All others:
  else
    window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
    = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

  function onchange (evt) {
    var v = "visible", h = "hidden",
        evtMap = {
          focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h
        };

    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.type in evtMap)
      console.log(evtMap[evt.type]);//Troque aqui pelo ajax
    else
      console.log(this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible");//Troque aqui pelo ajax
  }

  // set the initial state (but only if browser supports the Page Visibility API)
  if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
    onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
})();
```

`onfocusin` e `onfocusout` são [necessários para o IE9 e mais antigos](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus), enquanto que todos os outros fazem uso de `onfocus` e `onblur`, exceto para iOS, que usa `onpageshow` e `onpagehide`.

Aonde estão os `console.log`s troque por um Ajax que avisará para o servidor que o usuário saiu ou entrou na página.